# Perl chdir fails with a glob pattern

Tags: perl, directory, glob, chdir

I am trying to do cd in my perl script. I am using the below command:

```
chdir "/home/test/test1/test2/perl*";
```

`perl*` value is actually `perl_0122_2044`, but this value may vary.

The above `chdir` command is not doing `cd` to the path. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you know it's not? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't see any error checking in that. Are you using the `autodie` pragma? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: The complete commands are as below:

    chdir "/home/test/test1/test2/perl*";
    exec "cat test.in | grep build | awk '{print \$2}'";

After executing the script, it is showing the error:

    cat: test.in: No such file or directory

Comment: You should put that in your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chdir` does not accept `*` and other expansion characters in the argument. Use `glob` or something similar for this to extract a **single** directory, then `chdir` to that. For example, this changes directory to the first `/home/test/test1/test2/perl*` it finds:

```
$dir = (glob "/home/test/test1/test2/perl*")[0];
# only change dir if any dir was found: 
if (-d $dir) {
    # fail if cannot change dir (or, even better, use autodie):
    chdir $dir or die "Could not change to $dir: $!";
}
```

Comment: And check that error, mostly to see the directory it tried: `chdir $dir or die "Could not change to $dir: $!";`

Comment: @briandfoy Thank you for the reminder, added this and one extra check!

Answer (score 4):

[chdir](http://p3rl.org/chdir) expects a path, not a wildcard. Use [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) to expand the wildcard:

```
my ($dir) = glob "/home/test/test1/test2/perl*";
chdir $dir or die "$dir: $!";
```

If there are multiple expansions, the first one will be used.

Answer (score 0):

In similar vein, glob is handled by a module in [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) https://modules.raku.org/dist/IO::Glob